# How can I get table values from a website with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping

I am using a python script to get a certain text from a website (http://www.opensiteexplorer.org/) or (https://beswick.net/api-code/state-of-digital-example.php) or (https://smallseotools.com/domain-authority-checker/)
I would like to get all result values like "Page Authority" and "Domains Authority" and filter them out.
I am using python2.7 and BeautifulSoup to extract the data.

I am using this code:

```
def parse_url()
url = "https://beswick.net/api-code/state-of-digital-example.php"
domain = 'http://www.google.com'
mozID=" "
mozSEC=" "
def parse_url():
    r = requests.post(url, {'moz-member':mozID,'moz-secret': mozSEC,   'url_form': domain, 'Check Metrics': 'submit'})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml")
    for table in soup.find_all('table'):
    print table.text
parse_url()
```

and

```
def PageDomainAuthority():
        url = "https://smallseotools.com/domain-authority-checker/"
        domain = 'www.google.com' 
        r = requests.post(url, {'urls': domain, 'check': 'submit'})
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml")
        for p in soup.find_all("div",{"class":"col-sm-12 noP"}):
            print(p.text)
PageDomainAuthority()
```

here is the output(i can only get the headers) :

```
Web Page
DA
PA
Moz Rank
IP Address
IP Location
```

how can I get the values as well?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't obtain the values using BeautifulSoup, as they are not in the source code. You may need Selenium.

Comment: kitman0804  they are not in the source code of the main page, but whenever you load the page with the certain domain name, they should be in the source code.

Comment: any update?????

Comment: Sorry, I don't have `requests` right now and can't install it for some reasons. Take a look at `print(r.content)`, do you find the values you want?

Comment: thank you kitman0804, no I am still trying to get the values, the point is I cannot use Selenium

Comment: If you can't find the value in `r.content`, it is not possible to use `BeautifulSoup`, nor `lxml` to get the data.

Comment: here is how the authority work after printing out the r.content
($( "#resultsTable" ).find( "tr[url='"+resp.urls[index]+"'] .domainAuth").html(info.domain_auth))
seetms something happening in the background. I can see, there is no way to get the values by BeautifulSoup.as no more options remain, any idea how can I get the values by Selenium?

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to get the values for Moz Domain Authority, Page Authority and others using the approach you are trying to use. To get these values, you need to make use of [Mozscape API](https://moz.com/help/links-api/getting-started/example-api-call)'s provided by Moz. You can also refer the Java code to get the [Moz Domain Authority](https://www.myjavacode.com/java-api-to-get-domain-authority-and-other-moz-url-metrics/) and other metrics in [GitHub](https://github.com/clhprasanna/DomainMetrics). You should be able to follow similar steps and get the Moz domain metrics using Python as well.